# Multivariate regression for dataset with several dependent variables?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I'm looking at whether bottle size, design etc. has an effect on perceived value, perceived quality etc. So first set are the independent variables and the second are dependent variables.

Would multivariate regression work to answer this research question?

Comment: Your question seems kind of vague...

Comment: How can I make it more specific?

Comment: What is the "perceived value, perceived quality etc"?

Comment: Those are all numerical variables from 1 to 100. The respondant is shown a picture of a bottle with a specific type, design etc. and rates certain parameters from 1 to 100.

Comment: I think the multivariate regression(do you mean the multivariate logistic regression or others?) is just like bivariate logistic regression and the dependence doesn't matter in such scenarios.

Comment: Right, I've just heard some people using ANOVA in similar situations and I'm not sure.

Comment: You may want to consider Seemingly Unrelated Regression to account for correlations of e.g. value and quality from the same respondent.